# Is there a way to prevent a WMX user from adding an embedded attachment?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-workflow-manager, administration

I would like to allow `Linked` and `URL` attachments but **prevent** embedded attachments.

[image]

The `ManageAttachments`  [image]  privilege seems to be all or nothing.  Does anyone else require this particular configuration? How did you accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up as a workaround: adding a trigger to the JTX_JOB_ATTACHMENTS table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRG_BLOCKEMBEDDED_ATTCH
   ON  dbo.JTX_JOB_ATTACHMENTS
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @updateCount int
    DECLARE @insertCount int 

    select @updateCount = count(*) from deleted where ATTACHMENT_DATA is not null;
    select @insertCount = count(*) from inserted where ATTACHMENT_DATA is not null;

    IF (@insertCount + @updateCount) > 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Embedded attachments cannot be made to this WMX repository.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END 
END
GO
```

In Workflow Manager, when a user attempts to add an embedded attachment, they receive this error message:

[image: Error message in Workflow Manager]